# How to make hostile mobs passive using commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a Minecraft Bedrock Realm and one of my friends wants to have a mob army. So with commands I worked out how to summon mobs and how to equip armor and tools but my main issue is how to make them passive to the player. I tried `/scoreboard` and nothing obvious worked. I have been finding that the Java Minecraft `/team` command worked perfectly.

Is there anything like it for Bedrock? Just for verification, I am on Minecraft Bedrock version 1.19.20.